# Full screen issue in flex

Tags: apache-flex, fullscreen

My application has a layout where we have a fixed left hand side and a variable right hand side (occupies remaining space). We display a video in the right side which is sometimes bigger than the right hand side canvas and hence the canvas has scroll bars in some cases. Now we have a requirement where the video on the right must go "Full screen." I am able to go full screen but the issues that I am facing are :

1. Since the video has scrolls, I am not able to get the rectangle on "stage" to set to the stage's "fullScreenSourceRect" property.
2. The approach that I am taking is to set the video to occupy just the canvas on the right and then go full screen, but since the canvas on right is not the same aspect ratio as the screen we get empty spaces on either sides in the full screen view.
3. If we try to make the video display occupy just a smaller region of the right canvas (which is of the same ratio as the screen) and then go full screen then since the video was compressed before going full screen, we get a blurry video.

Any suggestions as to how to go about this would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding specifically what you're asking.  Perhaps if you showed some code or linked to a project sample.

Comment: The main issue is to take a video full screen. The video is larger than the size of the canvas in which it is displayed (hence the video is not completely visible on the screen without scrolling) Does this make sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this util class that does a great job of handling full-screen views: [FullScreenUtil](http://blog.appdivision.com/2009/09/08/flex-full-screen-utility/)

Comment: I will use this class and get back with the results.

Comment: This class turned out to be useful and we could directly use the class to go full screen with any component without adding and removing components from the stage.